# Angular.js not working on IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I developed a WebSite with Angular. It works great on all the browsers, but some users, me included, are experiencing issues on Internet Explorer. They just visualize a blank white page with no errors.
I am using Angular v.1.4.0-rc.0 and IE 11.0. I don't know the IE version used by the other users.

Adding `xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"` to the `<html>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"
                xmlns:og="https://ogp.me/ns#" 
                xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" 
                ng-app="ugh" ng-strict-di>

<head>
```

, now it shows the error

```
[$injector:modulerr] Module Error, failed to instantiate module ugh to: {1}
```

where ugh is the name of the main module.
I've just tried also with the manual Angular bootstrap but nothing changes.

This is the website [UrbanGenHome](http://www.urbangenhome.it)

[UPDATE1]

This is how my modules are structured:

```
angular.module('ugh.homePageModule', []);   
angular.module('ugh.paperSubPageModule', []);   
angular.module('ugh.components', []);
angular.module('ugh.call4paperPageModule', []); 
angular.module('ugh.feesPageModule', []);
angular.module('ugh.committeePageModule', []);  
angular.module('ugh.miscModule', []);   
angular.module('ugh.dnaPageModule', []);    

angular.module('ugh', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute','ngAnimate','metatags', 'ugh.components', 'ugh.homePageModule','ugh.paperSubPageModule', 'ugh.call4paperPageModule', 'ugh.feesPageModule', 'ugh.committeePageModule', 'ugh.miscModule', 'ugh.dnaPageModule'
                          ])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)
       {
          $routeProvider   
               .when('/home',{
                      templateUrl: 'pages/home/home.html',
                    })      
               .when('/paperSub',{
                      templateUrl: 'pages/paperSub/paperSub.html',
                      reloadOnSearch:false
                    })                                                                                          
              .otherwise({ templateUrl: 'pages/home/home.html',
                         });   
          }]);
```

And here is how I add the modules to `index.html`

```
!-- ANGULAR -->
<!-- Angular core JavaScript-->        
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>      
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <script src='./js/app.module.js'></script>
    <script src='./pages/misc/navbar/navbarDirective.js'></script>
    <script src='./pages/home/homeDirective.js'></script>  
    <script src='./pages/paperSub/paperSubDirective.js'></script>        
    <script src='./pages/paperSub/paperSubController.js'></script>   
    <script src='./pages/call4paper/call4paperController.js'></script>   
    <script src='./pages/call4paper/call4paperDirective.js'></script>     
    <script src='./pages/fees/feesController.js'></script>
    <script src='./pages/fees/feesDirective.js'></script>    
    <script src='./pages/committee/committeeController.js'></script>   
    <script src='./pages/misc/miscDirective.js'></script>    
    <script src='./pages/dna/dnaController.js'></script> 
    <script src='./pages/dna/dnaDirective.js'></script>
```

Comment: *"I don't know the IE version used by the other users"*  ... that part is important since support for versions less than 10 may mean you need an older version of angular

Comment: However I have version 11, and still get the error

Comment: modified the question, including me as tester :)

Comment: But you aren't wanting `xhtml`. You have an html5 doctype. Not sure why you add that

Comment: since [here] (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) it suggests to add it  if I use `ng:` notation.  Actually I use `ng-` , so it's not needed... but I tried and at least, now I have an error.  I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Ok, so, some module failed to instantiate. Are you going to show the module to us?

Comment: Are you even using `ng:` notation? that's different than `ng-` notation ... `ng:click` vs `ng-click`

Comment: Additionally, are you positive your IE isn't running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the HTML there is no way to know what you have loading and in what order. More info needed. Post your code.

Comment: If IE 11 doesn't throw error when you remove all those attributes on html tag then you need to find out what versions that users are having problems with. Try Changing browser mode (emulate) in IE and see what happens

Comment: IE isn't running in compatibility mode. I added some other code to my question. I don't know users versions, but I have IE11 and I have the same problem, so I can start fixing the error for v.11 at least

Comment: Is there a reason your various angular code isn't using the same version? That could be an issue.

Comment: oh sorry, I'am using 1.4.0 ... it way just my fault on copy-past the code here. Fixed it.

Comment: Plus version is a major version first `rc` which isn't good idea in production site either and sanitize isn't same version

Comment: got it. Thank you. Changed all to 1.4.0.  Same error.   Just tried also with 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about JQuery. I used a local version... linking it with cdn, now it works. Maybe I had a corrupted version? I really don't know how this could be related... but after a couple of days of tries, now it works.
Thank you to all for the support

Comment: i dont have JQuery locally, but still ie shows only blank page, doesnt load my app.

Comment: can you see my page ? www.urbangenhome.it?  try to change the order of how you import your .js files

Comment: yes I can see your site, working well, what your site has is my next target to learn how to make that nav bar small on scroll down and scroll the page on clicking on elements, I will try your suggestion and change order of .js. Can you suggest tutorials / tools / libs for learning things I mentioned?

Comment: not a particular tutorial...you should just check the page's scroll position, and then change the size of the navbar